# HAPI JS Node js creating https server

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

How do I create a *hapi* `http` and `https` server, listening on both 80 and 443  with the same routing?

(I need a server which should run both on http and https with the exact same API)

Comment: You can redirect all the requests form http to https.

Comment: var http = require('http'), https = require('https'), express = require('express'), app = express();
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer({ ... }, app).listen(443);  I was thinking something like this? Cant we do this in hapi?

Comment: No, I was suggesting why don't you redirect all http requests to https instead. see https://github.com/bendrucker/hapi-require-https

Comment: hey Codelion, do you know any ebooks (free/cost), for learning hapi js, i want to know more about hapi, i have searched over documentaion, but may be if i got cookbook or something then i learn more..

Comment: I am not aware of any books as such but you can try the following tutorial which I found helpful - https://github.com/nelsonic/learn-hapi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68138/discussion-between-codelion-and-sathish).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@codelion has given a good answer, but if you still want to listen on multiple ports, you can pass multiple configs for connections.

```
var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 80, /*other opts here */});
server.connection({ port: 8080, /*other opts, incl. ssh */  });
```

But to note again, it would be good to start depreciating http connections. Google and others will soon start marking them insecure.
Also, it would probably be a good idea to actually handle SSL with nginx or something, not on node app itself.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: wouldn't you want a secure connection between the hapi server and the nginx proxy server as well?

Comment: server.connection - not available now. Use multiply servers instanses

Comment: Nice to see that answers from 5 years ago still get some love :)  Most likely both the question and the answer(s) are long outdated.

Answer (score 24):

It may not be usual to handle the https requests directly on the application, but Hapi.js can handle both http and https within the same API.

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var server = new Hapi.Server();

var fs = require('fs');

var tls = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem')
};

server.connection({address: '0.0.0.0', port: 443, tls: tls });
server.connection({address: '0.0.0.0', port: 80 });

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply('Hello, world!');
    }
});

server.start(function () {
    console.log('Server running');
});
```

Comment: I tried this same code with my correct domain name but got an ENOENT error. Did you ever run into any issues around that due to permissions or anything?

Comment: Ports under 1024 are privileged and need root access.

Comment: does that mean you need to run your node app using root? Seems rather like a bad idea.

Answer (score 7):

You can redirect all http requests to https instead :

```
if (request.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'http') {
  return reply()
    .redirect('https://' + request.headers.host + request.url.path)
    .code(301);
}
```

Check out https://github.com/bendrucker/hapi-require-https for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Visit Link: http://cronj.com/blog/hapi-mongoose

Here is [a sample project](https://github.com/gauravgupta90/Hapi-Mongoose-Angular) which can help you with this.

For hapi version earlier than 8.x

```
var server = Hapi.createServer(host, port, {
    cors: true
});

server.start(function() {
    console.log('Server started ', server.info.uri);
});
```

For hapi new version

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: app.config.server.port });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [local-ssl-proxy npm package](https://github.com/cameronhunter/local-ssl-proxy) to proxy local HTTPS to HTTP. For local development only.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like this and found out https://github.com/DylanPiercey/auto-sni which has an example usage with Express, Koa, Hapi (untested)

It's basically based on letsencrypt certificates and load hapi server using a custom listener.

Haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

In reply to the selected answer: this does not work anymore, removes in version 17 :

https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/3572

You get :

```
TypeError: server.connection is not a function
```

Workaround is either using a proxy or creating 2 instances of `Hapi.Server()`